# Calculus question about symmetry of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-23}^{44} (x-a)^8 \, dx$$, what would a have to be for us to take advantage of even symmetry and evaluate half of the interval?

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) about how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Here an **easy approach** is just to perform a change of variable
$$
\int_{-23}^{44} (x-a)^8 \:dx=\int_{-23-a}^{44-a} u^8 \:du=\left[\frac{u^9}{9} \right]_{-23-a}^{44-a}=\frac{(44-a)^9+(23+a)^9}{9}
$$